# Рекурсивные запросы с использованием Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице: `flights (id,origin_apt, destination_apt, departure_time, arrival_time)`

Мне нужно, построить маршруты для перелета с условием что может быть как прямой рейс из точки A в точку Z, так и с пересадками из точки A в точку B, затем из точки B в точку Z  и так далее
Максимальное число пересадок 5.

Я начал делать это с помощью запросов в Postgres, но мне удалось сделать только прямой рейс и с одной пересадкой

А вот осилить маршруты с 3-5 пересадками, мне не хватает знаний:

A -> Z

A -> B -> Z

A -> B -> C -> Z

A -> B -> C -> D -> Z

A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> Z

```
WITH RECURSIVE segs AS (
  SELECT f0.id::text as flights
            , origin_apt, destination_apt
            , departure_time AS departure
            , arrival_time AS arrival
            , 1 as hops
            , (arrival_time - departure_time)::interval AS total_time
            , '00:00'::interval as waiting_time
  FROM flights f0
  WHERE origin_apt = 'SVX' -- <ORIGIN_APT = SVX>
  AND departure_time >= '2016-01-19'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.flights || '-->' || f1.id::text as flights
            , s.origin_apt, f1.destination_apt
            , s.departure AS departure
            , f1.arrival_time AS arrival
            , s.hops + 1 AS hops
            , s.total_time + (f1.arrival_time - f1.departure_time)::interval AS total_time
            , s.waiting_time + (f1.departure_time - s.arrival)::interval AS waiting_time
  FROM segs s
     JOIN flights f1
       ON f1.origin_apt = s.destination_apt
       AND f1.departure_time >= s.arrival + '8 hour' -- <DEFAULT_TRANSIT_TIME = 8 hours >
)
SELECT *
FROM segs
WHERE destination_apt = 'PEK' -- <DESTINATION_APT = PEK>
AND waiting_time < '25 day'-- <DEFAULT_DELIVERY_DAYS = 25 day>
ORDER BY departure, waiting_time asc;
```

Пример данных:

```
CREATE TABLE flights
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  origin_apt character varying,
  destination_apt character varying,
  departure_time timestamp without time zone,
  arrival_time timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT flights_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into flights VALUES
(1,'GOJ','TAS','2016-01-04 06:00','2016-01-04 11:30'),
(2,'GOJ','TAS','2016-01-11 06:00','2016-01-11 11:30'),
('3','GOJ','TAS','2016-01-18 06:00','2016-01-18 11:30'),
('4','GOJ','TAS','2016-01-25 06:00','2016-01-25 11:30'),
('5','GOJ','TAS','2016-02-01 06:00','2016-02-01 11:30'),
('6','GOJ','TAS','2016-02-08 06:00','2016-02-08 11:30'),
('7','GOJ','TAS','2016-02-15 06:00','2016-02-15 11:30'),
('8','GOJ','TAS','2016-02-22 06:00','2016-02-22 11:30'),
('9','GOJ','TAS','2016-02-29 06:00','2016-02-29 11:30'),
('10','GOJ','TAS','2016-03-07 06:00','2016-03-07 11:30'),
('11','GOJ','TAS','2016-03-14 06:00','2016-03-14 11:30'),
('12','GOJ','TAS','2016-03-21 06:00','2016-03-21 11:30'),
('13','GOJ','DYU','2016-01-02 03:40','2016-01-02 09:30'),
('14','GOJ','DYU','2016-01-09 03:40','2016-01-09 09:30'),
('15','GOJ','DYU','2016-01-16 03:40','2016-01-16 09:30'),
('16','GOJ','DYU','2016-01-23 03:40','2016-01-23 09:30'),
('17','GOJ','DYU','2016-01-30 03:40','2016-01-30 09:30'),
('18','GOJ','DYU','2016-02-06 03:40','2016-02-06 09:30'),
('19','GOJ','DYU','2016-02-13 03:40','2016-02-13 09:30'),
('20','GOJ','DYU','2016-02-20 03:40','2016-02-20 09:30'),
('21','GOJ','DYU','2016-02-27 03:40','2016-02-27 09:30'),
('22','GOJ','DYU','2016-03-05 03:40','2016-03-05 09:30'),
('23','GOJ','DYU','2016-03-12 03:40','2016-03-12 09:30'),
('24','GOJ','DYU','2016-03-19 03:40','2016-03-19 09:30'),
('25','GOJ','DYU','2016-03-26 03:40','2016-03-26 09:30'),
('26','TAS','PEK','2016-01-06 13:40','2016-01-06 22:00'),
('27','TAS','PEK','2016-01-13 13:40','2016-01-13 22:00'),
('28','TAS','PEK','2016-01-20 13:40','2016-01-20 22:00'),
('29','TAS','PEK','2016-01-27 13:40','2016-01-27 22:00'),
('30','TAS','PEK','2016-02-03 13:40','2016-02-03 22:00'),
('31','TAS','PEK','2016-02-10 13:40','2016-02-10 22:00'),
('32','TAS','PEK','2016-02-17 13:40','2016-02-17 22:00'),
('33','TAS','PEK','2016-02-24 13:40','2016-02-24 22:00'),
('34','TAS','PEK','2016-03-02 13:40','2016-03-02 22:00'),
('35','TAS','PEK','2016-03-09 13:40','2016-03-09 22:00'),
('36','TAS','PEK','2016-03-16 13:40','2016-03-16 22:00'),
('37','TAS','PEK','2016-03-23 13:40','2016-03-23 22:00'),
('38','PRG','PEK','2016-01-08 13:00','2016-01-09 05:55'),
('39','PRG','PEK','2016-01-15 13:00','2016-01-16 05:55'),
('40','PRG','PEK','2016-01-22 13:00','2016-01-23 05:55'),
('41','PRG','PEK','2016-01-29 13:00','2016-01-30 05:55'),
('42','PRG','PEK','2016-02-05 13:00','2016-02-06 05:55'),
('43','PRG','PEK','2016-02-12 13:00','2016-02-13 05:55'),
('44','PRG','PEK','2016-02-19 13:00','2016-02-20 05:55'),
('45','PRG','PEK','2016-02-26 13:00','2016-02-27 05:55'),
('46','PRG','PEK','2016-03-04 13:00','2016-03-05 05:55'),
('47','PRG','PEK','2016-03-11 13:00','2016-03-12 05:55'),
('48','PRG','PEK','2016-03-18 13:00','2016-03-19 05:55'),
('49','PRG','PEK','2016-03-25 13:00','2016-03-26 05:55'),
('50','PRG','PEK','2016-01-04 13:00','2016-01-05 06:00'),
('51','PRG','PEK','2016-01-11 13:00','2016-01-12 06:00'),
('52','PRG','PEK','2016-01-18 13:00','2016-01-19 06:00'),
('53','PRG','PEK','2016-01-25 13:00','2016-01-26 06:00'),
('54','PRG','PEK','2016-02-01 13:00','2016-02-02 06:00'),
('55','PRG','PEK','2016-02-08 13:00','2016-02-09 06:00'),
('56','PRG','PEK','2016-02-15 13:00','2016-02-16 06:00'),
('57','PRG','PEK','2016-02-22 13:00','2016-02-23 06:00'),
('58','PRG','PEK','2016-02-29 13:00','2016-03-01 06:00'),
('59','PRG','PEK','2016-03-07 13:00','2016-03-08 06:00'),
('60','PRG','PEK','2016-03-14 13:00','2016-03-15 06:00'),
('61','PRG','PEK','2016-03-21 13:00','2016-03-22 06:00'),
('62','GYD','PEK','2016-01-03 19:20','2016-01-04 06:20'),
('63','GYD','PEK','2016-01-10 19:20','2016-01-11 06:20'),
('64','GYD','PEK','2016-01-17 19:20','2016-01-18 06:20'),
('65','GYD','PEK','2016-01-24 19:20','2016-01-25 06:20'),
('66','GYD','PEK','2016-01-31 19:20','2016-02-01 06:20'),
('67','GYD','PEK','2016-02-07 19:20','2016-02-08 06:20'),
('68','GYD','PEK','2016-02-14 19:20','2016-02-15 06:20'),
('69','GYD','PEK','2016-02-21 19:20','2016-02-22 06:20'),
('70','GYD','PEK','2016-02-28 19:20','2016-02-29 06:20'),
('71','GYD','PEK','2016-03-06 19:20','2016-03-07 06:20'),
('72','GYD','PEK','2016-03-13 19:20','2016-03-14 06:20'),
('73','GYD','PEK','2016-03-20 19:20','2016-03-21 06:20'),
('74','GYD','PEK','2016-03-27 19:20','2016-03-28 06:20'),
('75','MUC','SVX','2016-01-16 10:40','2016-01-16 19:20'),
('76','MUC','SVX','2016-01-23 10:40','2016-01-23 19:20'),
('77','MUC','SVX','2016-01-30 10:40','2016-01-30 19:20'),
('78','MUC','SVX','2016-02-06 10:40','2016-02-06 19:20'),
('79','MUC','SVX','2016-02-13 10:40','2016-02-13 19:20'),
('80','MUC','SVX','2016-02-20 10:40','2016-02-20 19:20'),
('81','MUC','SVX','2016-02-27 10:40','2016-02-27 19:20'),
('82','MUC','SVX','2016-03-05 10:40','2016-03-05 19:20'),
('83','MUC','SVX','2016-03-12 10:40','2016-03-12 19:20'),
('84','MUC','SVX','2016-03-19 10:40','2016-03-19 19:20'),
('85','MUC','SVX','2016-03-26 10:40','2016-03-26 19:20'),
('86','PRG','SVX','2016-01-07 16:25','2016-01-08 00:40'),
('87','PRG','SVX','2016-01-14 16:25','2016-01-15 00:40'),
('88','PRG','SVX','2016-01-21 16:25','2016-01-22 00:40'),
('89','PRG','SVX','2016-01-28 16:25','2016-01-29 00:40'),
('90','PRG','SVX','2016-02-04 16:25','2016-02-05 00:40'),
('91','PRG','SVX','2016-02-11 16:25','2016-02-12 00:40'),
('92','PRG','SVX','2016-02-18 16:25','2016-02-19 00:40'),
('93','PRG','SVX','2016-02-25 16:25','2016-02-26 00:40'),
('94','PRG','SVX','2016-03-03 16:25','2016-03-04 00:40'),
('95','PRG','SVX','2016-03-10 16:25','2016-03-11 00:40'),
('96','PRG','SVX','2016-03-17 16:25','2016-03-18 00:40'),
('97','PRG','SVX','2016-03-24 16:25','2016-03-25 00:40'),
('98','PRG','SVX','2016-01-03 10:10','2016-01-03 18:15'),
('99','PRG','SVX','2016-01-10 10:10','2016-01-10 18:15'),
('100','PRG','SVX','2016-01-17 10:10','2016-01-17 18:15'),
('101','PRG','SVX','2016-01-24 10:10','2016-01-24 18:15'),
('102','PRG','SVX','2016-01-31 10:10','2016-01-31 18:15'),
('103','PRG','SVX','2016-02-07 10:10','2016-02-07 18:15'),
('104','PRG','SVX','2016-02-14 10:10','2016-02-14 18:15'),
('105','PRG','SVX','2016-02-21 10:10','2016-02-21 18:15'),
('106','PRG','SVX','2016-02-28 10:10','2016-02-28 18:15'),
('107','PRG','SVX','2016-03-06 10:10','2016-03-06 18:15'),
('108','PRG','SVX','2016-03-13 10:10','2016-03-13 18:15'),
('109','PRG','SVX','2016-03-20 10:10','2016-03-20 18:15'),
('110','PRG','SVX','2016-03-27 10:10','2016-03-27 18:15'),
('111','SVX','GYD','2016-01-07 17:00','2016-01-07 19:00'),
('112','SVX','GYD','2016-01-14 17:00','2016-01-14 19:00'),
('113','SVX','GYD','2016-01-21 17:00','2016-01-21 19:00'),
('114','SVX','GYD','2016-01-28 17:00','2016-01-28 19:00'),
('115','SVX','GYD','2016-02-04 17:00','2016-02-04 19:00'),
('116','SVX','GYD','2016-02-11 17:00','2016-02-11 19:00'),
('117','SVX','GYD','2016-02-18 17:00','2016-02-18 19:00'),
('118','SVX','GYD','2016-02-25 17:00','2016-02-25 19:00'),
('119','SVX','GYD','2016-03-03 17:00','2016-03-03 19:00'),
('120','SVX','GYD','2016-03-10 17:00','2016-03-10 19:00'),
('121','SVX','GYD','2016-03-17 17:00','2016-03-17 19:00'),
('122','SVX','GYD','2016-03-24 17:00','2016-03-24 19:00'),
('123','SVX','GYD','2016-01-02 17:00','2016-01-02 19:00'),
('124','SVX','GYD','2016-01-09 17:00','2016-01-09 19:00'),
('125','SVX','GYD','2016-01-16 17:00','2016-01-16 19:00'),
('126','SVX','GYD','2016-01-23 17:00','2016-01-23 19:00'),
('127','SVX','GYD','2016-01-30 17:00','2016-01-30 19:00'),
('128','SVX','GYD','2016-02-06 17:00','2016-02-06 19:00'),
('129','SVX','GYD','2016-02-13 17:00','2016-02-13 19:00'),
('130','SVX','GYD','2016-02-20 17:00','2016-02-20 19:00'),
('131','SVX','GYD','2016-02-27 17:00','2016-02-27 19:00'),
('132','SVX','GYD','2016-03-05 17:00','2016-03-05 19:00'),
('133','SVX','GYD','2016-03-12 17:00','2016-03-12 19:00'),
('134','SVX','GYD','2016-03-19 17:00','2016-03-19 19:00'),
('135','SVX','GYD','2016-03-26 17:00','2016-03-26 19:00'),
('136','SVX','DYU','2016-01-07 06:45','2016-01-07 09:55'),
('137','SVX','DYU','2016-01-14 06:45','2016-01-14 09:55'),
('138','SVX','DYU','2016-01-21 06:45','2016-01-21 09:55'),
('139','SVX','DYU','2016-01-28 06:45','2016-01-28 09:55'),
('140','SVX','DYU','2016-02-04 06:45','2016-02-04 09:55'),
('141','SVX','DYU','2016-02-11 06:45','2016-02-11 09:55'),
('142','SVX','DYU','2016-02-18 06:45','2016-02-18 09:55'),
('143','SVX','DYU','2016-02-25 06:45','2016-02-25 09:55'),
('144','SVX','DYU','2016-03-03 06:45','2016-03-03 09:55'),
('145','SVX','DYU','2016-03-10 06:45','2016-03-10 09:55'),
('146','SVX','DYU','2016-03-17 06:45','2016-03-17 09:55'),
('147','SVX','DYU','2016-03-24 06:45','2016-03-24 09:55'),
('148','SVX','DYU','2016-01-05 06:45','2016-01-05 09:55'),
('149','SVX','DYU','2016-01-12 06:45','2016-01-12 09:55'),
('150','SVX','DYU','2016-01-19 06:45','2016-01-19 09:55'),
('151','SVX','DYU','2016-01-26 06:45','2016-01-26 09:55'),
('152','SVX','DYU','2016-02-02 06:45','2016-02-02 09:55'),
('153','SVX','DYU','2016-02-09 06:45','2016-02-09 09:55'),
('154','SVX','DYU','2016-02-16 06:45','2016-02-16 09:55'),
('155','SVX','DYU','2016-02-23 06:45','2016-02-23 09:55'),
('156','SVX','DYU','2016-03-01 06:45','2016-03-01 09:55'),
('157','SVX','DYU','2016-03-08 06:45','2016-03-08 09:55'),
('158','SVX','DYU','2016-03-15 06:45','2016-03-15 09:55'),
('159','SVX','DYU','2016-03-22 06:45','2016-03-22 09:55'),
('160','SVX','DYU','2016-01-02 06:45','2016-01-02 09:55'),
('161','SVX','DYU','2016-01-09 06:45','2016-01-09 09:55'),
('162','SVX','DYU','2016-01-16 06:45','2016-01-16 09:55'),
('163','SVX','DYU','2016-01-23 06:45','2016-01-23 09:55'),
('164','SVX','DYU','2016-01-30 06:45','2016-01-30 09:55'),
('165','SVX','DYU','2016-02-06 06:45','2016-02-06 09:55'),
('166','SVX','DYU','2016-02-13 06:45','2016-02-13 09:55'),
('167','SVX','DYU','2016-02-20 06:45','2016-02-20 09:55'),
('168','SVX','DYU','2016-02-27 06:45','2016-02-27 09:55'),
('169','SVX','DYU','2016-03-05 06:45','2016-03-05 09:55'),
('170','SVX','DYU','2016-03-12 06:45','2016-03-12 09:55'),
('171','SVX','DYU','2016-03-19 06:45','2016-03-19 09:55'),
('172','SVX','DYU','2016-03-26 06:45','2016-03-26 09:55'),
('173','SVX','TAS','2016-01-04 07:40','2016-01-04 10:50'),
('174','SVX','TAS','2016-01-11 07:40','2016-01-11 10:50'),
('175','SVX','TAS','2016-01-18 07:40','2016-01-18 10:50'),
('176','SVX','TAS','2016-01-25 07:40','2016-01-25 10:50'),
('177','SVX','TAS','2016-02-01 07:40','2016-02-01 10:50'),
('178','SVX','TAS','2016-02-08 07:40','2016-02-08 10:50'),
('179','SVX','TAS','2016-02-15 07:40','2016-02-15 10:50'),
('180','SVX','TAS','2016-02-22 07:40','2016-02-22 10:50'),
('181','SVX','TAS','2016-02-29 07:40','2016-02-29 10:50'),
('182','SVX','TAS','2016-03-07 07:40','2016-03-07 10:50'),
('183','SVX','TAS','2016-03-14 07:40','2016-03-14 10:50'),
('184','SVX','TAS','2016-03-21 07:40','2016-03-21 10:50'),
('185','SVX','PEK','2016-01-07 19:45','2016-01-08 04:00'),
('186','SVX','PEK','2016-01-14 19:45','2016-01-15 04:00'),
('187','SVX','PEK','2016-01-21 19:45','2016-01-22 04:00'),
('188','SVX','PEK','2016-01-28 19:45','2016-01-29 04:00'),
('189','SVX','PEK','2016-02-04 19:45','2016-02-05 04:00'),
('190','SVX','PEK','2016-02-11 19:45','2016-02-12 04:00'),
('191','SVX','PEK','2016-02-18 19:45','2016-02-19 04:00'),
('192','SVX','PEK','2016-02-25 19:45','2016-02-26 04:00'),
('193','SVX','PEK','2016-03-03 19:45','2016-03-04 04:00'),
('194','SVX','PEK','2016-03-10 19:45','2016-03-11 04:00'),
('195','SVX','PEK','2016-03-17 19:45','2016-03-18 04:00'),
('196','SVX','PEK','2016-03-24 19:45','2016-03-25 04:00'),
('197','SVX','PEK','2016-01-05 19:45','2016-01-06 04:00'),
('198','SVX','PEK','2016-01-12 19:45','2016-01-13 04:00'),
('199','SVX','PEK','2016-01-19 19:45','2016-01-20 04:00'),
('200','SVX','PEK','2016-01-26 19:45','2016-01-27 04:00'),
('201','SVX','PEK','2016-02-02 19:45','2016-02-03 04:00'),
('202','SVX','PEK','2016-02-09 19:45','2016-02-10 04:00'),
('203','SVX','PEK','2016-02-16 19:45','2016-02-17 04:00'),
('204','SVX','PEK','2016-02-23 19:45','2016-02-24 04:00'),
('205','SVX','PEK','2016-03-01 19:45','2016-03-02 04:00'),
('206','SVX','PEK','2016-03-08 19:45','2016-03-09 04:00'),
('207','SVX','PEK','2016-03-15 19:45','2016-03-16 04:00'),
('208','SVX','PEK','2016-03-22 19:45','2016-03-23 04:00'),
('209','SVX','PEK','2016-01-08 19:45','2016-01-09 04:00'),
('210','SVX','PEK','2016-01-15 19:45','2016-01-16 04:00'),
('211','SVX','PEK','2016-01-22 19:45','2016-01-23 04:00'),
('212','SVX','PEK','2016-01-29 19:45','2016-01-30 04:00'),
('213','SVX','PEK','2016-02-05 19:45','2016-02-06 04:00'),
('214','SVX','PEK','2016-02-12 19:45','2016-02-13 04:00'),
('215','SVX','PEK','2016-02-19 19:45','2016-02-20 04:00'),
('216','SVX','PEK','2016-02-26 19:45','2016-02-27 04:00'),
('217','SVX','PEK','2016-03-04 19:45','2016-03-05 04:00'),
('218','SVX','PEK','2016-03-11 19:45','2016-03-12 04:00'),
('219','SVX','PEK','2016-03-18 19:45','2016-03-19 04:00'),
('220','SVX','PEK','2016-03-25 19:45','2016-03-26 04:00'),
('221','SVX','PEK','2016-01-03 19:45','2016-01-04 04:00'),
('222','SVX','PEK','2016-01-10 19:45','2016-01-11 04:00'),
('223','SVX','PEK','2016-01-17 19:45','2016-01-18 04:00'),
('224','SVX','PEK','2016-01-24 19:45','2016-01-25 04:00'),
('225','SVX','PEK','2016-01-31 19:45','2016-02-01 04:00'),
('226','SVX','PEK','2016-02-07 19:45','2016-02-08 04:00'),
('227','SVX','PEK','2016-02-14 19:45','2016-02-15 04:00'),
('228','SVX','PEK','2016-02-21 19:45','2016-02-22 04:00'),
('229','SVX','PEK','2016-02-28 19:45','2016-02-29 04:00'),
('230','SVX','PEK','2016-03-06 19:45','2016-03-07 04:00'),
('231','SVX','PEK','2016-03-13 19:45','2016-03-14 04:00'),
('232','SVX','PEK','2016-03-20 19:45','2016-03-21 04:00'),
('233','SVX','PEK','2016-03-27 19:45','2016-03-28 04:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш запрос уже может выбирать любые вложенности рекурсии. Ваши исходные данные для тестов не содержат подходящих маршрутов, что бы запрос мог выдать больше стыковок. При добавлении записи `insert into flights VALUES(234,'DYU','PRG','2016-02-18 09:00','2016-02-18 15:30')` ваш запрос сразу начинает находить еще кучу вариантов, к сожалению очень многие с повторным пролетом через Кольцово. Так что запрос надо ограничивать, не позволяя выбирать маршруты в которых один и тот же АП встречается более одного раза. Примерно так:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE segs AS (
  SELECT f0.id::text as flights
            ,'/'||origin_apt||'/'||destination_apt||'/' as route   -- <-- Добавил полный маршрут
            , origin_apt, destination_apt
            , departure_time AS departure
            , arrival_time AS arrival
            , 1 as hops
            , (arrival_time - departure_time)::interval AS total_time
            , '00:00'::interval as waiting_time
  FROM flights f0
  WHERE origin_apt = 'SVX' -- <ORIGIN_APT = SVX>
  AND departure_time >= '2016-01-19'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.flights || '-->' || f1.id::text as flights
            ,s.route||f1.destination_apt||'/'   -- <-- добавляем АП посадки в маршрут
            , s.origin_apt, f1.destination_apt
            , s.departure AS departure
            , f1.arrival_time AS arrival
            , s.hops + 1 AS hops
            , s.total_time + (f1.arrival_time - f1.departure_time)::interval AS total_time
            , s.waiting_time + (f1.departure_time - s.arrival)::interval AS waiting_time
  FROM segs s
     JOIN flights f1
       ON f1.origin_apt = s.destination_apt
       AND f1.departure_time >= s.arrival + '8 hour' -- <DEFAULT_TRANSIT_TIME = 8 hours >
       AND NOT s.route like '%/'||f1.destination_apt||'/%'  -- <-- АП назначения не в полном маршруте
       AND s.hops < 5
)
SELECT *
FROM segs
WHERE destination_apt = 'PEK' -- <DESTINATION_APT = PEK>
AND waiting_time < '25 day'-- <DEFAULT_DELIVERY_DAYS = 25 day>
ORDER BY departure, waiting_time asc;
```

Comment: А как можно ограничить запрос что бы он не строил маршрут больше чем из 5-и пересадками, что бы максимум было A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> Z  потому, что сейчас он строит запросы с неограниченным кол-вом пересадок типа A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> H -> J -> K -> X -> Z

Comment: Во второй части union `AND s.hops<4`, цифру на 1 меньше, потому что один перелет она еще добавит после сработки условия.