# Технология решения алгоритмических задач на SQL

Tags: sql, алгоритм, oracle

Какие подходы применяются для решения алгоритмических задач на чистом SQL, без использования процедурных расширений?
Например, задача о поиске кратчайшего пути в графе. Возникают вопросы - как реализовать обход графа, как хранить промежуточные значения вычислений, как задать критерий остановки алгоритма.
В качестве СУБД пусть будет Oracle.
Кажется, что основным подходом является использование иерархических запросов, но какие структуры данных использовать (строки?) и как отобразить алгоритмические операторы языков общего назначения (условия, циклы) на SQL, не очень понятно.

Comment: Как подсказывает капитан, SQL не предназначен для решения алгоритмических задач, он предназначен для создания запросов к базе данных. Поэтому никакой "технологии решения алгоритмичеких задач на чистом SQL" не существует. Алгоритмы нужно реализовывать не запросами, а либо на клиентской стороне, либо в хранимых функциях.

Comment: На самом деле, существует. Реляционная алгебра довольно мощная штука. Плюс, мы можем использовать SQL-операторы, специфичные для СУБД. Или вы можете доказать, что существует алгоритмическая задача, принципиально не решаемая на SQL?

Comment: Вот например подобная задача http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484289

Comment: @Mike хороший пример, спасибо.

Comment: Накопление данных - обычно строки с разделителями, в том примере есть полный текущий маршрут `route` позволяющий не летать кругами A->B->A->B. условия - обычно все в where. Цикл - сама рекурсия. Рекурсивная часть запроса получает на входе строки с предыдущей итерации, как и в классическом цикле это состояние вычислений оставшееся с предыдущего прогона

Comment: А на счет технологии ... фантазии побольше нужно ... К одной задачке на enSO я 4 дня пытался подступиться, 3 попытки заканчивались "все, невозможно", на 4й день вдруг понял, что рекурсию можно  рассмотреть как классический цикл, в котором есть общее состояние и абстрактный  номер итерации. А данные можно подтягивать не по предыдущим данным (как обычно принято в рекурсивных запросах), а по этому номеру, ну т.е. "обрабатываем N-ю строку" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305300/

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз пошла такая пьянка, дайте и мне похвастаться... волновой алгоритм, диалект MySQL.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Wave;

DELIMITER @@

CREATE PROCEDURE Wave (IN NodeFrom INT, IN NodeTo Int)
/*
Поиск пути в направленном взвешенном ненормированном графе от NodeFrom до NodeTo волновым алгоритмом.
Допустимы изолированные вершины, дольность, контуры, кратные рёбра, мультиграф, листья, петли и пр.

Функциональность модифицируется комментариями в коде.
С обоими комментариями - ищет наиболее дешёвый путь из не более чем MaxIterations шагов.
Если раскомментировать *1 - ищет наиболее дешёвый из максимально коротких длиной не более чем MaxIterations шагов.
Если раскомментировать *2 - ищет наиболее дешёвый путь из всех возможных.
Если раскомментировать *1 и *2 - ищет наиболее дешёвый из максимально коротких.
Если путь не найден - возвращает 0 записей, иначе одну с путём и его стоимостью.

Макс. длина пути - VARCHAR(65000)

Ожидаемая структура исходных данных:

CREATE TABLE Graph (
point1 INT, -- Начало ребра 
point2 INT, -- Конец ребра ребра 
weight INT, -- Стоимость ребра, больще нуля
);
*/
BEGIN
/*1 DECLARE Done INT DEFAULT 0;*/
DECLARE MaxIterations INT DEFAULT 100;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Routes;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Routes(point INT, weight INT, route VARCHAR(65000), PRIMARY KEY(point)) ENGINE = MEMORY;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Step;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Step(point INT, weight INT, route VARCHAR(65000)) ENGINE = MEMORY;
/*2 SELECT COUNT(*)-1 INTO MaxIterations FROM Graph;*/
INSERT INTO Routes(point, weight, route) 
  VALUES (NodeFrom, 0, CAST(NodeFrom AS CHAR));
WHILE /*1 Done = 0 AND*/ MaxIterations > 0 DO
  TRUNCATE Step;
  INSERT INTO Step (point, weight, route)
  SELECT Graph.point2, Routes.weight+Graph.weight, CONCAT(Routes.route, '/', CAST(Graph.point2 AS CHAR))
  FROM Routes, Graph
  WHERE Routes.point = Graph.point1;
  INSERT IGNORE INTO Routes (point, weight, route)
    SELECT point, weight, route FROM Step;
  UPDATE Routes, Step
    SET Routes.weight = Step.weight, Routes.route = Step.route
    WHERE Routes.point = Step.point AND Routes.weight > Step.weight;
  /*1 SELECT COUNT(point) INTO Done
    FROM Routes
    WHERE point = NodeTo;*/
    SET MaxIterations = MaxIterations - 1;
END WHILE;
SELECT weight, route
  FROM Routes
  WHERE point = NodeTo;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Routes;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Step;
END; @@

DELIMITER ;

/* 
=============================
Демонстрация работы процедуры 
=============================
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Graph;

/* Создание таблицы для хранения направленного графа */

CREATE TABLE Graph (
point1 INT NOT NULL, /* Начало ребра */
point2 INT NOT NULL, /* Конец ребра ребра */
weight INT NOT NULL, /* Стоимость ребра */
PRIMARY KEY (point1, point2)
)  ENGINE = MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FillGraph;

DELIMITER @@

CREATE PROCEDURE FillGraph (IN VergesCount INT, IN NodesCount INT, IN MaxWeight INT)
/* 
Процедура заполнения таблицы графа случайными данными 

VergesCount - количество рёбер
NodesCount - количество вершин
MaxWeight - максимальная стоимость ребра
*/
BEGIN
WHILE VergesCount > 0 DO
  INSERT IGNORE INTO Graph (point1,point2,weight)
    SELECT CEILING(NodesCount * RAND()),CEILING(NodesCount * RAND()),CEILING(MaxWeight * RAND());
  SET VergesCount = VergesCount - 1;
END WHILE;
DELETE FROM Graph WHERE point1 = point2;
END; @@

DELIMITER ;

CALL FillGraph (6000, 2000, 100); /* Тестовое заполнение графа */

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Graph; /* Просмотр количества сгенерированных рёбер. Меньше заданного - отсев дубликатов и замыканий */

/* Тестовые запуски */

CALL Wave(1,9);
CALL Wave(2,6);

/* Удаление тестовых объектов */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Graph;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Wave;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FillGraph;
```

Comment: Похвастайтесь этим же алгоритмом,  но реализованном в виде одного запроса SELECT).

Comment: В рамках диалекта MySQL это невозможно. В нём даже рекурсивных запросов нет.

Comment: а в рамках диалектов с рекурсивными запросами?

Answer (score 0):

Однажды я решал задачу по поиску кратчайшего пути в графе как раз на SQL (правда на PostgreSQL, но это не суть). Вот тело основного метода, непосредственно занимающегося поиском:

```
CREATE FUNCTION prepare_route(s text, d text) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
    _seek integer;
    _t integer;
    _cnt integer;
    _prev_cnt integer;
    _reach bool;
BEGIN
  _seek = (SELECT nextval('seek_id_seq'));

  INSERT INTO route_seeker(seek_id, node_id, reach_time, prev_node)
    VALUES(_seek, d, 0, 0);

  _t = 0;
  _cnt = 0;
  _prev_cnt = -1;
  _reach = false;

  WHILE NOT _reach AND _cnt - _prev_cnt > 0 LOOP
    _t = _t + 1;
    INSERT INTO route_seeker(seek_id, node_id, reach_time, prev_node)
      SELECT _seek, start, _t, finish
       FROM edges WHERE finish IN (
       SELECT node_id 
       FROM route_seeker 
         WHERE seek_id = _seek AND reach_time = _t-1)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    _reach = (SELECT count(node_id)=1 FROM route_seeker WHERE seek_id = _seek AND node_id = s);
    _prev_cnt = _cnt;
    _cnt = (SELECT count(node_id) FROM route_seeker);
  END LOOP;

  return _seek;
END;
$$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.prepare_route(s text, d text) OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: FUNCTION prepare_route(s text, d text); Type: COMMENT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COMMENT ON FUNCTION prepare_route(s text, d text) IS 'Start a new seek operation and find the shortes route from node s to node d. Id of the started seek operation is returned. Prepared route could be then extracted by build_prepared_route() function; or it length may be estimated by get_prepared_route_length() function.';
```

А вот - формирование массива по ранее найденному пути:

```
CREATE FUNCTION build_prepared_route(seek integer, s text, d text) RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE _route text[];
BEGIN
  _route = (WITH RECURSIVE route AS (
      SELECT node_id, prev_node
      FROM route_seeker 
      WHERE seek_id = seek AND route_seeker.node_id = s 
      UNION ALL 
        SELECT route_seeker.node_id, route_seeker.prev_node
        FROM route, route_seeker
        WHERE seek_id = seek AND route.prev_node = route_seeker.node_id)
    SELECT array_agg(node_id) FROM route);
  IF _route IS NULL THEN
    _route = array[]::text[];
  END IF;
  RETURN _route;
END;
$$;
ALTER FUNCTION public.build_prepared_route(seek integer, s text, d text) OWNER TO postgres;
--
-- Name: FUNCTION build_prepared_route(seek integer, s text, d text); Type: COMMENT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--
COMMENT ON FUNCTION build_prepared_route(seek integer, s text, d text) IS 'Build an array representing the shortest path from node s to node d which was prepared in current seek.';
```

Схему БД целиком можно найти тут: https://github.com/Pankraty/graph/blob/master/database%20schema/graph_db.sql. На идеальное решение не претендую, но рабочее как минимум )

Comment: Есть один нюанс: по условию решение должно быть на чистом SQL, без использования функций и процедур.

Comment: Да, тогда это решение само по себе не подойдет, но, возможно, поможет вам в поиске. У меня такого ограничения не было; реализовывал на стороне СУБД, чтобы избежать перекачивания всего графа на клиент, что было бы крайне неэффективно в случае большого разреженного графа.

Comment: @Aleksei вопрос именно в том, как решать задачи при наличии ограничений.