# Нужна помощь с иерархическим запросом SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужна помощь с запросом:

> Номера поездов, на которых можно сегодня проехать от станции Сумы в Киев, не более чем с 2 пересадками

Есть ER-схема структуры БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт генерации и заполнения таблиц:
http://rgho.st/7Qc8bntvy

> Может поможет скрипт для получения рейса, на котором можно добраться с Сум до Киев сегодня

```
SELECT v.*, to_char(vd.department_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM') "Department Time",  
to_char(vd.arrival_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM') "Arrival Time"  
FROM ( 
   SELECT st.voyage_code connect_code FROM station_type st WHERE st.station_id in( 
      SELECT s.station_id FROM station s WHERE s.city in('Сумы','Киев') 
   ) HAVING count(st.voyage_code) > 1 GROUP BY st.voyage_code 
) c 
JOIN voyage v ON(v.voyage_code = c.connect_code) 
JOIN voyage_date vd ON(vd.voyage_code = v.voyage_code) 
WHERE to_date(vd.department_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') = to_date(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: Информации в БД не достаточно. надо знать какой поезд во сколько прибывает на каждую из станций следования. иначе велик риск показать пересадку на поезд, который к нужному времени уже ушел. Когда добавите время на каждой станции заодно не надо будет помечать начальная/конечная, по времени будет видно. Вообще что то подобное делал тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484289/484309#484309  в оракле аналогично, только слово recursive не требуется

Comment: @Mike а если не учитывать фактор времени, а просто следовать связи Рейс - Станция и по нему искать другие рейсы проходящие через эти станции. Искать Киев и чтобы LEVEL не превышал 2. Не могу сформировать примерную структуру запроса. Спасибо за комментарий

Comment: почему у вас having до group by идёт?

Comment: @Denis по тому что я группирую совпадающий рейс (выводит рейс 775П в котором есть Сумы и такой же по тому что там есть Киев) и потом я все рейсы группирую и вывожу те у которых совпадение по станции было больше чем 1 (может не самый крутой запрос, но имеет право на жизнь :) )

Comment: Ну общую структуру видно по ссылке в первом комменте. в первой части рекурсивного CTE select из station_type по станции Сумы. во второй части (после union all) подклеиваете к имени запроса еще раз station_type по условию что поезд другой (можно ограничить пойдя поглубже в таблицы по дате). обязательно собираете id поездов в route, что бы не взять один поезд дважды и поле hops в том запросе - это как раз количество пересадок