# Рекурсионный запрос в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, рекурсия

Помогите плиз с рекурсионным запросом, никак не могу с условием справится, он у меня в итоге зацикливается
Есть таблица

```
id1.        id2.        c1. c2. 
"161202"    "066900"    21  20
"161005"    "067405"    21  20
"107903"    "105005"    24  201
"105005"    "107903"    201 24
"121101"    "136605"    24  21
"164107"    "120202"    21  24
"126505"    "099707"    24  25
"099707"    "126505"    25  24
"126105"    "091404"    24  25
"091404"    "126105"    25  24
"129207"    "110304"    24  25
"110304"    "129207"    25  24
"128007"    "113707"    24  25
"113707"    "128007"    25  24
"136605"    "121101"    21  24
"161401"    "110200"    21  25
"110200"    "161401"    25  21
"066900"    "161202"    20  21
"067405"    "161005"    20  21
"078503"    "112507"    20  25
"065908"    "112808"    20  25
"110802"    "086800"    25  26
"076003"    "083906"    20  26
"077002"    "084701"    20  26
```

я например хочу выстроить все возможные "нити" от с1 = 20(20->21->24->201) и тд. Сделал рекурсию, но очень сильно ограничил условиями, это не подходит, если убрать условия, то естественно с1 пересекается с с2, так как 20->21 он попадает на строку 21->20 и на этом все, зацикливается

Вопрос как раз в том, как ограничить условия, чтобы не было пересечений, а только движение "вперед". Условие table.c2 <> rec.c1 не работает. То есть, хотел применить, чтобы если в рекурсии есть с1=20, то из таблице ее не брать.

Цель задачки: 
Это список пограничных переходов между жд разных стран, то есть 
id1,2 - это пограничные станции, с1,2 - это код страны.
Я хочу повторить нитку из станы 20 до 24, в итоге я хочу получить все возможные нити.
Результат вывода примерно такой 20/21/24
Это коды стран и пограничные станции, например по станции id1="066900"("066900"    "161202"    20  21), должны быть только вот эти нитки,

```
   id1.  нитка из стран. код транзитной станы. погранстанции
1)"066900" 20/21/24      21                    "161202"/"164107"
2)"066900" 20/21/24      21                    "161202"/"136605"
```

Comment: А можно вас попросить добавить, какой результат должен быть? Что в конечно итоге надо будет получить.

Comment: Добавил результат, если понятно так, суть такова, что мне нужно построить возможные нитки транзитные через страны по жд, важны еще как раз станции транзитные получать, так как я буду считать расстояние. Я сделал запрос, но пришлось ограничивать много, что не подходит мне. В идеале, я далее все это помещу в процедуру и на входи подавать буду только код страны отправления, код страны назначения. Но я к сожалению не спец в SQL ((

Comment: @Axenow мне сейчас даже больше нужно, чтобы мне помогли ограничить выборку в нерекурсионной части и в рекурсионной, чтобы избежать пересечений.

Comment: Я не самый большой эксперт в SQL, но без вашего дополнения многие просто не захотят отвечать, потому что из условия не было ясно, что надо получить в конце.

Comment: @Axenow ну вот сейчас достаточно информации, или нет?

Comment: Мне да, но я пока не знаю, как это точно сделать.

Comment: Вот и я, работает только тогда. когда обложить ограничениями с2. Но это не подходит(

Comment: @Владислав У меня не осталось тех запросов, которые когда то делал под вашу задачу. Но там точно это было. Надо собрать полный путь (из стран или из станций), вот прямо такой как вы хотите в поле "Нитка из стран" (только `/` и в начале и в конце) и в рекурсивной части проверять, что станция(страна) которая сейчас проверяется еще не входит в эту нитку. Проверяется обычно like на вхождение. в этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484309/194569 примере посмотрите как собирается поле route и посмотрите на условие с этим полем в рекурсивной части (`NOT s.route like '%/'||f1.destination_apt||'/%'`)

Comment: @Mike, большое вам спасибо в очередной раз :) понял свою ошибку, сейчас все получилось, нитки построились :) Я неверно джойнил в итоге.